# unable to add or change Sheet trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have triggers set up to run on a sheet when a certain form is submitted (as well as a minor hourly one). That have and still run perfectly, but I am now having a problem setting a new script to trigger. Whether I try to change the hourly trigger to include the new script or add a new script, I get the error:

> "We're sorry, a server error had occurred. Please wait a bit and try
>   again."

So it seems I am unable to add or update any triggers on this sheet.

Comment: Possibly the same underlying issue as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267236/forms-on-submit-trigger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this issue too. If you added new authorizations to a script and try to add a trigger you will get this error message. You can solve it by running a random function to re-authorize the script.